# ¿Para que sirven los tres puntos (...) en el parámetro de una método de AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Este código es un ejemplo de [AsyncTask | Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) y no entiendo para qué sirven los 3 puntos `...` después del tipo del parámetro. Veo que en `URL` e `Integer` lo colocan pero no en `Long`. No entiendo la diferencia.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             totalSize += Downloader.downloadFile(urls[i]);
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Los tres puntos `...` indican que se pueden pasar un número arbitrario de argumentos, ya sea en forma de `array` o de forma secuencial. Es lo que se conoce en java como `Varargs`.

En tu caso, lo que permite es procesar una o más `URLs` (un número indeterminado de ellas) en segundo plano.

Como peculiaridad, este método se puede utilizar con más argumentos en una función, pero siempre tienen que ir posicionados en último lugar, por ejemplo:

```
public void multiplicar(int num, int... nums) {
    // código
}
```

Tienes muy buena información al respecto en muchos hilos de SO, como [éste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12665769/what-does-the-three-dots-in-doinbackgroundurl-urls-mean) o [éste](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3158730/java-3-dots-in-parameters), y en la [documentación de Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).